# Gtk.CssProvider not working in Gtk3 Python3?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, gtk3

I am trying to set style in a python 3 with Gtk3 from `gi.repository` in Fedora 32, but it just does nothing.

I used to do this in Gtk2 and python2 with

```
settings = gtk.settings_get_for_screen(gdk.screen_get_default())
gtk.rc_parse_string(...) 
gtk.rc_reset_styles(settings)
```

This worked fine.

Now, in Python 3 with Gtk3 from `gi.repository` I tried this, just to make the background red.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk
....

class Ave:
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        css_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
        css_provider.load_from_data(b'GtkWindow { background-color: #ff0000; }')
        screen = gdk.Screen.get_default()
        gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
        ...

Ave()
gtk.main()
```

I also tried with `css_provider.load_from_path('./ave_style.css')` without success (the program even complains if `ave_style.css` has errors, so it is loaded. I even tried with `gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION`.

Yet, nothing happens. The program completely ignores the `CSS` styles.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using GTK < 3.20, that snippet of CSS is not valid.

If you want to match a GtkWindow, you must use the `window` selector, [as the documentation describes](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#id-1.3.6.2.11.4).

You also want to use `Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION` for style introduced by your application, either programmatically or by custom resources; the `USER` priority is for user-provided CSS files.

Comment: Its was that, thanks. How do I know the element name "translations"?

Comment: The selectors are always documented in the API reference of each class.